# Get logon username in elevated script with standard user account

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-7

In my batch script run within Windows 7, I have several IF clauses like:

```
IF "%USERNAME%"=="foo" GOTO bar
```

Unfortunately, when I run this batch script elevated with "*Run as administrator*" from the Context Menu, the `%USERNAME%` is always the administrator's username, not the username of the current active logon user.

The same applies to `whoami` in an elevated batch script.

`QUERY USER` gives me a list of all users currently logged on, not merely the one user I am looking for.

A standard user account, unlike an administrator account that can elevate from user group token to administrator group token while keeping the same user environment, actually loads the administrator account environment when "*Run as administrator*" is selected.

Is there a way to get the current active logon username instead of the administrators username?

Comment: @Compo @michael_heath It seems I didn't explain the problem properly. So to clarify, the problem exists in the moment when a logged in user (non-admin) chooses to run a script as an admin. If someone is logged in as user1 (non-admin) and then the admin chooses to run a program with "Run as administrator" (user2) then the batch script `%USERNAME%` shows the admin's name (user2). I am the admin of a Windows 7 PC and sometimes a normal user is logged in, and I need to start a program with administrator privileges but I want to access the logged in user's username.

Comment: @Compo, when a Windows user (non-admin), say "pupil123", is logged in, and then I, the admin ("teacheradmin1"), right click on a program and choose "Run as administrator" (= me) on a .bat file and type in my password in the UAC prompt, then `echo %username%` shows my username ("teacheradmin1"), not the username of the user that is logged in ("pupil123"). My question is whether it's possible to show the username of the logged in user instead of the run-as-admin user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### WMIC ComputerSystem Get UserName

```
@echo off
setlocal

rem Get logon username without the leading "computername\" string.
set "user="

for /f "skip=1 tokens=1,* delims=\" %%A in (
    'wmic computersystem get username ^|findstr /r /v "^$"'
) do for %%C in (%%~B) do if not defined user set "user=%%~C"

echo "%user%"
pause
```

Using  the `for /f` option `skip=1`, as the 1st line is the `UserName` header that is not wanted. Delimit by `\` as the value will be like `computername\username` and get the remainder in the 2nd token. Pipe to `findstr` to ignore empty lines. 2nd `for` loop will get the first value free of whitespace characters.

Piping `wmic` output to `powershell` to cleanup the output tests better than piping to `findstr`, and the use of a 2nd `for` loop is not needed.

```
@echo off
setlocal

rem Get logon username without the leading "computername\" string.
set "user="

for /f "skip=1 tokens=1,* delims=\" %%A in ('
    wmic computersystem get username ^|
    powershell -noprofile -command "$input.trim()"
') do set "user=%%~B"

echo "%user%"
pause
```

Use `command /?` for more help. Most commands in the code will display help with the `/?` argument at a Command Prompt.

#### Query User alias QUser

```
@echo off
setlocal

rem Get logon username.
set "user="

for /f %%A in ('quser^|findstr /b /c:">"') do set "user=%%~A"

if defined user if "%user:~0,1%" == ">" set "user=%user:~1%"

echo "%user%"
pause
```

The leading `>` in `quser` (*an alias for* `query user`) indicates the currently logged on username, not the administrator's username.

Use `%user%` instead of `%username%` where needed.

Notes:

- Due to `for /f` loop getting username from the default option of `token=1`, if username contains a space or tab, then this will get only the characters that precede the space or tab.
- On a 64 bit OS, `quser.exe` exists in `System32`, not in `SysWOW64`. A 32 bit `cmd.exe` on a 64 bit OS may not be recognized as a command.

References:

- [query user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/query-user)
- [Query User / QUSER](https://ss64.com/nt/query-user.html)

Comment: Thank you so much, @michael_heath! Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work in all command shells. When I start cmd.exe from Total Commander (both elevated and not elevated) or when I use the cmd shell from MobaXTerm, then I get `'quser' is not recognized as an internal or external command`. You also suggested another solution: `wmic computersystem get username` which works in every cmd window. Is there a way to utilize `wmic` in a batch file to get the username?

Comment: If those programs are 32 bit, then `quser.exe` may not be found as `quser.exe` is not in the `SysWOW64` directory. You could possibly use `%SystemRoot%\SysNative\quser.exe` on a 64 bit OS as `SysNative` will redirect and access `quser.exe` in `System32`. Added WMIC code.

Comment: Beautiful! Your code works! @michael_heath, you're a wonderful person. Knowledgeable, helpful and friendly! And quick! Thank you so much.

Comment: Shortened version: `for /f "tokens=2 delims=\" %%f in ('wmic computersystem get username') do set "LoggedOnUser=%%f"`