# How to get the desktop path of the original non-admin user when running a python file as admin

Tags: python, shortcut, win32com

I am trying to use win32com to create a shortcut to my user's desktop.  When I use the code below, I am calling os.environ['USERPROFILE'] with join to Desktop or winshell.desktop() to get the path to the user's desktop.  However, since this needs to be ran as an admin, it is only grabbing the admin's desktop path and not the intended user's.  Is there a way to get the actual logged-in user's desktop path when running a python script as an admin?

This is the entire code.  The line in part in question is the second try statement.

```
import pathlib
import os, winshell
import os.path
from os import path
from win32com.client import Dispatch
import zipfile
import ctypes

def Mbox(title, text, style):
    return ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, text, title, style)

def install():  
    try:
        if(os.path.exists(r"C:\Program Files\Report Builder")):
            Mbox('Error','That file already exists.',0)
            raise Exception('Error','That file already exists.')
        else:
            with zipfile.ZipFile(r"{}".format(str(pathlib.Path().absolute())+"\Report Builder.zip"), 'r') as zip_ref:
                zip_ref.extractall(r"C:\Program Files")
    except (Exception) as error:
        Mbox('Error',str(error),0)
    else:
        try:
            desktop = os.path.join(os.environ['USERPROFILE'],'Desktop')
            path = os.path.join(desktop, "Report Builder.lnk")
            target = r"C:\Program Files\Report Builder\dist\reportbuilder\reportbuilder.exe"
            wDir = r"C:\Program Files\Report Builder\dist\reportbuilder"
            icon = r"C:\Program Files\Report Builder\dist\reportbuilder\rbpuzz.ico"
            shell = Dispatch('WScript.Shell')
            shortcut = shell.CreateShortCut(path)
            shortcut.Targetpath = target
            shortcut.WorkingDirectory = wDir
            shortcut.IconLocation = icon
            shortcut.save()
        except (Exception) as error:
            Mbox('Error',str(error),0)
        else:
            Mbox('Success!','A shortcut has been added to your desktop.',0)
            
if __name__ == "__main__":
    install()
```

Comment: This might help you:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61397541/get-logon-username-in-elevated-script-with-standard-user-account

Comment: Is there a way to do this strictly in Python?  I am not as familiar with running batch files

Comment: Well, you can run `quser` or `wmic` with `subprocess.Popen` and read the output.  As an alternative, you could split this into two scripts: one to do the unzip that runs elevated, and one that does the shortcut (and perhaps calls the other) that does not run elevated.

Comment: Yeah, that may be my best option, but I will pursue the subprocess method.  Thank you!